# Show div onclick, add class, and get the same process on other divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

If a div with module ID is clicked, the div will get an extra class added "active". With that extra class, I make the border solid and show the row that has the same module. But I need to get help with my jQuery so the same process does work with the other divs too.

So if the next div is clicked, the previous clicked and active div needs to get his class removed (so deactive) and his row beneath hidden. The next selected div needs to get the same process as the previous.

**Can someone help me to put the information I have into the example jQuery below?**

```
//These are clickable images with dotted borders.
<div id="a-module" class="single_image series-border-dotted active">
<div id="b-module" class="single_image series-border-dotted">
<div id="c-module" class="single_image series-border-dotted">
<div id="d-module" class="single_image series-border-dotted">

//These rows are hidden on load. 
<div id="row-a-module">
<div id="row-b-module">
<div id="row-c-module">
<div id="row-d-module">

//jQuery what I have
$("#a-module").click(function(){
    $("#row-a-module").show();
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

//jQuery example that I maybe need.
$(".example").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.row').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + $(this).data('id')).fadeIn('slow');
});

//CSS
.series-border-dotted.active{border-style:solid!important;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class `module` to all `#*-module` divs. Add class `row-module` to all `#row-*-module` divs.

Then:

```
$('.module').click(function () {         // click on any module-div
    $('.module').removeClass('active');  // remove .active from all module-divs
    $(this).addClass('active');          // add .active to the clicked div

    $('.row-module').hide();             // hide all row-divs
    $('#row-' + this.id).show();         // show the corresponding row-div
});
```